# why is the file size different after loading and writing wav file with librosa

Tags: python, librosa

I am loading a wav file with librosa. after saving the file it is two times bigger. So I load it again and compare it with the original one. Somehow there is a difference.
Even if I load it twice and compare it, there is a huge difference between both data.

```
import librosa
wave1, sr1 = librosa.load('go.wav', mono=True, sr=None)
librosa.output.write_wav('go2.wav', wave1, sr1)
librosa.output.write_wav('go3.wav', wave1, sr1)

wave2, sr2 = librosa.load('go2.wav', mono=True, sr=None)
diff12 = sum(abs(wave1-wave2))
wave3, sr3 = librosa.load('go3.wav', mono=True, sr=None)
diff13 = sum(abs(wave1-wave3))
diff23 = sum(abs(wave2-wave3))
```

diff12 = 0.106048583984375

diff13 = 0.102630615234375

diff23 = 0.181884765625

what is the reason that the files are not the same?